# Singleton doesn't have unique instance Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, singleton, sqflite

I'm trying to implement the singleton pattern with null safety in Flutter, to do a unique instance for my sqflite database, but after initialization in the splashScreen, when I try to access it in another Widget, it seems that it's not the same instance since the database is not initialized. I tried to add a random() int to check if it has the same value in the different widget, and the value change each times I request it.

My code is like this :

```
class DatabaseHandler {
  final int random = new Random().nextInt(200);

  static final DatabaseHandler instance = new DatabaseHandler._internal();

  factory DatabaseHandler() {
    return instance;
  }

  DatabaseHandler._internal();

  late Database _database;

  Database getDb() {
    print(random);
    return _database;
  }

  Future<void> initDB() async {
    var path = await getDatabasesPath();
    var dbPath = join(path, 'test.db');

    Database dbConnection = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      return db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE favorite_page(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, isFavorite BOOL)",
      );
    });

    this._database = dbConnection;
  }
}
```

I got a "Not initialize exception" when I do getDb() even if I used initDB() in the splashScreen.

I call the singleton in two places :

The db is initialized here :

```
class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  static const String route = "/splash";

  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();

      PushNotificationService pushNotif = PushNotificationService();
      pushNotif.initialise();
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    initializeFlutterFire();
    DatabaseHandler().initDB();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Lottie.asset('assets/lotties/loading-screen.json',
                animate: true, repeat: true)));
  }
}
```

and used here :

```
class PagesDb {
  Future<FavoritePage> insert(FavoritePage page) async {
    var db = DatabaseHandler().getDb();
    await db.insert(tablePage, page.toMap());
    return page;
  }
}
```

But I tried to just use DatabaseHandler().getDb() in different widgets, they got the same random value, but not the same as in the splash screen

Comment: Can you put the code where you actually use this class? Also, before looking for other issues, are you sure initDB has completed before calling getDb? Consider that if getDatabasesPath or openDatabase never complete or throw an exception, _database will never get a value.

Comment: Sure i'll update the respond, I'm sure that initDb has completed the code because I tried adding a future<void> + then to the initDb to wait for the end of the method, but I got the same problem.

Comment: Not really a solution but I used https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#registering-singletons to create my singleton and now it's working

Comment: "I'm sure that initDb has completed the code because I tried adding a future<void> + then to the initDb to wait for the end of the method".  I don't understand what that means.  I don't see anything that prevents `getDb()` from being called before `initDb()` completes.  Also, it seems unclear to me how you observe different random numbers printed since the first call to `getDb()` would result in a `LateInitializationError` that would terminate your app.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the code that I present here was my final step but before that I tried many thing such as adding a return to the ``initDb()`` method so that in my splashScreen I had something like initDb().then { getDb(); }. With that, I knew that the initDb was finish and I would not have the LateInitializationError. But even with that, when I tried to access the database with getDb() later in the app, it was initialize

Comment: `DatabaseHandler().initDb().then((_) { DatabaseHandler().getDb(); }` does not prevent something else from calling `getDb()` before `initDb()` completes.  You need to provide evidence that `initDb()` completes before *any* call to `getDb()`.  A simple way to check would be to make `initDb` print a unique message at the very end.  I also am highly skeptical that you have multiple `DatabaseHandler` instances as claimed and still want to know how you can possibly observe multiple random numbers being printed when your app should crash after the first one.